# How to pick up specific data with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm Hiro from Japan.
I just started  studying Python with Selenium by myself.

I am happy if somebody help me solve following problem.

Number of "data" which is enclosed in "p" tags is always changed so don't know how many data will be shown every time.
Data4 is always appear but order is changed.
Also these data are assigned same class.

For example, In case sample A Data4 is 4th, but sample B is 2nd.
Please help me how pick up "Data4".

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
(sample A)
----------------------------------------
<div class="elist" id="test">
    <ul class="ijkl">
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data1</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data2</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data3</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data4</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
----------------------------------------

(sample B)
----------------------------------------
<div class="elist" id="test">
    <ul class="ijkl">
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data1</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="elRow">
            <div class="elRowTitle">
                <p>Code4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="elRowData">
                <p>Data4</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
----------------------------------------
```

I wrote the following script using "find_elements_by_xxxxx" method for both sample A and B but did not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe') 
elem_ItemCodes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div') 
elem_ItemCodes2 = elem_ItemCodes.find_elements_by_class_name('elRowData') 
elem_ItemCode = elem_ItemCodes2[3].text 
print(elem_ItemCode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parent as reference,

The xpath equivalent will be :

```
//div[@id="test"]//div[@class="elRowData"][4]/p
```

your approach is correct, but make few changes like:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe') 
elem_ItemCodes = driver.find_elements_by_id('test') 
elem_ItemCodes2 = elem_ItemCodes.find_elements_by_class_name('elRowData') 
elem_ItemCode = elem_ItemCodes2[4].find_elemen_by_tag_name("p").text 
print(elem_ItemCode)
```

The text is in P tag and the index in xpath starts from 1 and not 0